# Animated size modification using AHEasing in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, caanimation, catransaction

I'm trying to make a view change size using **AHEasing** by WarrenM https://github.com/warrenm/AHEasing
I have the point to point animation working, but the re-sizing doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty new at using **AHEasing** so I'm not sure what mistake I'm making.

From what I can tell the image "someImage" should be resizing from `CGSizeMake(300, 500)` to `CGSizeMake(100, 100)`, but the changes are completely ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImageView *someImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500);
    [self.view addsubview:someImage];
    [self animatedResize];
}


-(void)animatedResize{
    currentFunction = ExponentialEaseOut;
    CALayer *layer = [someImage layer];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

    CAAnimation *chase =[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"sizeChange" function:currentFunction fromSize:CGSizeMake(300, 500) toSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

    [chase setDelegate:self];
    [layer addAnimation:chase forKey:@"sizeChange"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If you don't know or you don't THINK so then the answer will be yes. You can't set the frames like this using auto layout

Comment: I'm not using auto layout. I usually disable it by default and I just double checked to make sure and it's auto layout is not checked